# Strong duality in conic programmig

Tags: linear-programming, conic-sections

Let $K$ be a convex cone which is not closed. The look at a probem of the from
$$\min <C,X>, \,s.t\; <A_i,X>=b_i,\, X\in C.$$
Now suppose I now that both this program and its dual have a strictily feasable point. Does then strong duality apply? In particular does this mean that the set of optimal points is compact?

Comment: Do you mean $X\in K$?